# Power factor down after solar connection

Tags: energy, solar-energy, power-factor-correction, meter, bidirectional

We installed solar plant in factory. After that power factor goes down to 0.16. Normally it never goes below 0.85 in history even if we keep APFC off. We always maintained it to 0.99. Note - Main meter is uni directional and not bidirectional.

Comment: What was your kva from utility before and after?  Also, how does utility charge for bad power factor (is it total kva dependent)?

Answer (score 3):

Solar panels can supply only real power, not reactive volt-amperes. If the factory supplies much of its own real power from solar panels, that reduces the real power received from the utility but not the reactive volt-amperes. The natural result is a low power factor at the meter. The remedy is to install a power factor compensation capacitor bank. That can be done as part of the solar panel power conversion unit, but was apparently not done in this case.

Comment: The inverters for the solar can provide leading power factor as well.  But, that would eat into the real power they provide unless the inverters are oversized.  Probably would be a good idea for him to contact the manufacturer and ask.

Comment: We have the APFC panel which maintains P. F. to 0.99 before solar connection.   C. T. of power factor correction panel is connected on grid.  Should it be after combination of solar and grid power  ?

Comment: I think APFC CT should be connected after the solar connection point. That should cause it to correct the power factor at the load. That should result in high power factor at the meter whether the solar panel supplies all of the real power or not.