# APFC C.T.Position

Tags: power, current, transformer, solar-cell, power-factor-correction

We installed on grid solar plant.
Before installation P. F. was always maintained to 0.99 by capacitor banks(APFC panel).
But after solar connection is varies and goes down up to 0.16.

APFC panel CT position is on grid only. Should it be after combination of solar and grid?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your previous question? [Power factor down after solar connection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/510375/power-factor-down-after-solar-connection)

Comment: The CT should remain where it is as it measures what is needed to adjust power factor of incoming AC from utility. Don't get hung-up on this - the previous answer you got is correct.